# Where is the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging temp path exactly

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I am making a small change to an existing application so that users can email us the log file when things go wrong. Even though it is c# the app is using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.

This gets setup like this:

```
FileLogTraceListener fileLogTraceListener = listener as FileLogTraceListener;
fileLogTraceListener.Location = LogFileLocation.TempDirectory;
```

My question is: Where do the log files go?

Is it the same place as [Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) ?

I have seen a bunch of other posts asking similar questions but I need to be sure that whatever computer / operating system this app runs on it is able to pick up the logs. I take it there is no way to look inside the FileLogTraceListener class to see what it does when working with temp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same place as Path.getTempPath(). Reflector showed me this:

```
private string get_LogFileName()
{
    string tempPath;
    switch (this.Location)
    {
        case LogFileLocation.TempDirectory:
            tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
            break;
```

+1 to Nate Bross - reflector helped to find the answer

Answer (score 2):

Failing documentation, you could:

- Use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look at the source
- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals to see what IO your process is doing.
- Write a test app that makes two files, one with `Path.GetTempPath()` and one with VB Logger.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at reflector - I know they are writing to the same place on my pc but am concerned that it could work differently under vista, windows server, etc.

Comment: @Pondidum it looks like its an Enum, so I don't think it will have a real path at runtime, at least that's expossed publicly from the class.